# Passing part of a URL to PHP and return results from a database

Tags: php, javascript

I'm working on an interactive map and I am wondering if it's possible to pass part of a URL to a PHP script and have it look up information and then fetch it back to display within an iframe in a lightwindow.

The map is CSS based and each the link on each state within the href contains the state name (e.g. - #statename).

When a user clicks on the map, the #statename is appended to the URL.

I'm wondering that if it's possible to pass that part of the URL (#statename) to PHP and have it run the script from there?

Here's a link to the interactive map that I am working on. If you click on the state of Texas you'll see what I mean:

http://sjdunham.com/beta/maptest/

Comment: Yes this is perfectly possible.

Comment: @PeeHaa I think named anchors are used only client-side

Comment: http://seidel.cust.he.net/Map/clientmap.html

Comment: @Mike That is correct. But surely you can think of a way to send it over to the serverside :) *cough cough* xhr is one that comes to mind ;)

Comment: @PeeHaa Dag nabbit. You're right. it *is* perfectly possible!

Answer (score 0):

Yep, it's fairly easy, you could bind an event to the hashchange event, if you are using jQuery, you could do something like this:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
   console.log(window.location.hash); // replace this
});
```

You can then replace the console.log line with an ajax call to the PHP script and use whatever you send back to modify the iframe when the request is done.